# AWS SQS send message to queue work on serverless offline but not aws server when deployed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send message to AWS SQS queue, when trying **LOCALLY** with `serverless offline start --stage test` message get to the queue successfully. However when I deploy this on server with `sls deploy --stage test` the `sqs.sendMessage()` does not get executed. I am saying this because I am logging success and failure message on console and none of them are printing.

here is the snippet of the send message function from node

index.js file

```
let params = {
  MessageBody: smessage,
  QueueUrl:
    "https://sqs.zone.amazonaws.com/client_id/sqsname"
};

console.log("=====sqs start+++++ line 133 +++++");
console.log("params line 134", params);
sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("+++++++++++++++SQS Error+++++++++");
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("+++++++++++++++SQS SUCCESS+++++++++");
    console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

serverless.yml file

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
      Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:zone:clientid:sqsname"
```

When I call that end pojnt locally by running `sls offline start --stage test` I get SQS SUCCESS with success message id

But in case of when deployed to server none of the statement get executed.

Please help

Comment: It sounds to me that your server has no permission to access the queue. Does it have an IAM user or role that it's using?

Comment: Thank you @howcheng for your effort, but it is fixed now.

Comment: how you solved it?